# In custom reverse vector iterator don't see first element

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, reverse-iterator, spdlog

The other day I wanted to try writing my own iterators for a vector, of course, the most primitive example, since there is a lot of confusing code in the c++ standards. So the usual iterator for a vector in the forward direction works fine, but there was a problem with the reverse iterator. I have it completely built on the base iterator, only I changed / inverted the operators specifically for the reverse iterator.

```cpp
template<typename Vector>
class VectorRevIterator : public VectorIterator<Vector> //This is normal (work) vector iterator
{
public:
    using Base = VectorIterator<Vector>;

    VectorRevIterator(PointerType ptr) noexcept : Base(ptr) {};

    VectorRevIterator(const VectorRevIterator& other) : Base(other) { *this = other; };

    VectorRevIterator& operator++()
    {
        Base::operator--(); //--ptr;
        return *this;
    }

    VectorRevIterator operator++(int)
    {
        VectorRevIterator itr = *this;
        Base::operator--(); //--*this;
        return itr;
    }

    VectorRevIterator& operator--()
    {
        Base::operator++(); //++ptr;
        return *this;
    }

    VectorRevIterator operator--(int)
    {
        VectorRevIterator itr = *this;
        Base::operator++(); //++*this;
        return itr;
    }

    VectorRevIterator& operator+=(const PointerType otherPtr)
    {
        Base::operator-=(otherPtr); //ptr -= otherPtr;
        return *this;
    }

    VectorRevIterator operator+(const PointerType otherPtr)
    {
        VectorRevIterator itr = *this;
        Base::operator-(otherPtr); // itr -= otherPtr
        return *this;
    }

    VectorRevIterator& operator-=(const PointerType otherPtr) { return Base::operator+=(otherPtr); }
    VectorRevIterator operator-(const PointerType otherPtr) { Base::operator+(otherPtr); }
    ReferenceType operator*() const { return *ptr; }
    PointerType operator->() const { return std::_Const_cast(Base::operator->()); }
};
```

Access to iterator from Vector:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Vector
{
public:
        using ValueType = T;
        using PointerType = ValueType*;
        using ReferenceType = ValueType&;
        
        using ReverseIterator = VectorRevIterator<Vector<T>>;
public:
       T* data;
       size_t size;
       size_t capacity;
...

// construct/destructor
// custom allocator
// index operators

...

ReverseIterator rBegin() { return ReverseIterator(data + size); }
ReverseIterator rEnd() { return ReverseIterator(data); }

};
```

The problem itself is that when I try to go through all the elements in the opposite direction `VectorRevIterator`. When trying to output all this to the console, it seems to shift one element forward and does not see/cannot read the characters of the first element. But then output all the elements, only without the last one.

Here a example:

```cpp
Vector<String> values;
values.emplaceBack("1");
values.emplaceBack("2");
values.emplaceBack("3");
values.emplaceBack("4");
values.emplaceBack("5");

Vector<String>::ReverseIterator revIt = values.rBegin();

// output with spdlog
for (revIt; revIt != values.rEnd(); ++revIt)
        INFO(*revIt); // error on first iteration, but print only 1, 2, 3, 4

// ouput with std::cout
for (revIt; revIt != values.rEnd(); ++revIt)
        std::cout << *revIt << std::endl; // doesn't print anything
```

How solve this problem? To make reverse iterator it just need to revert operators `++` `--` `+=` `-=` and `rBegin` `rEnd` functions. Or maybe im forgotten about something?

Comment: I started to guess what the problem is, but in a normal iterator, its end is the next element in memory (the idea of which does not exist, those beyond the boundary of the vector (`data + size`)). And when I do the same scheme in `VectorRevIterator` only in reverse, then for it the beginning becomes (`data + size`) that goes beyond its limits in memory (those element before the beginning of the iterator itself). That is, how do I get the following element (`data + size` )?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rBegin()` returns an iterator to the first element:

```
ReverseIterator rBegin() { return ReverseIterator(data + size); }
```

But it's pointing one element beyond the end and can't be dereferenced. You need to dereference the element before it.

You could therefore adjust the dereference operator in the `VectorRevIterator` version:

```
ReferenceType operator*() const { return *std::prev(ptr); }
```

Comment: @KennyTutorials Another option is of course to use [`std::reverse_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator)

Comment: Yea but I just want to understand how std::reverse_iterator itself works, which is why I create my own.